# Custom list + JSP + java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, jsp

I want to implement custom JSP list tag, but have problem with accessing properties of custom list object.  With example like below accessing a `name` property of `List2` on `test.jsp` page give an error `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"`. How to solve this ?

```
public class List2 extends ArrayList<String> {

    public String getName() {
        return "name";
    }
}
```

test.jsp

```
<%-- java.lang.NumberFormatException --%>
${list.name}

<%-- this works ok --%>
<c:forEach  items="${list}" var="item">
   ${item}  
</c:forEach>
```

**EDIT**

Whole `test.jsp` working

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:forEach  items="${list}" var="item">
   ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

Whole `test.jsp` **NOT** working

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
${list.name}
```

TestController.java:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @ModelAttribute("list")
    public List2 testList() {
        List2 l = new List2();
        l.add("foo");
        l.add("bar");
        return l;
    }

    /* test.jsp */
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Any more information on the JSP? The expression works, which is indicated by the exception. But some code on your JSP seems to try and parse it as a number.

Comment: can you post the code that produces thsi

Comment: @Jigar `${list.name}` produces error

Comment: what is `list` in JSP context?

Comment: Did you mean ${list.name} in your Whole test.jsp NOT working?

Comment: Also, can you post the code that puts list in the JSP context, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's due to the fact that the JSP EL allows using `.` or `[]` to access object properties. But both have a special meaning for `List` instances: it means access to the nth element. You may thus write `${list[2]}` or `${list.2}`. Since EL detects that your object is an instance of a collection, it tries to transform name into a number, and you get this exception.

Note that this is only an explanation of the exception you get. I haven't checked the specification to see if it's a bug of Tomcat or if it's expected behavior.

You should very very rarely extend `ArrayList`. Most of the time, it's better to use delegation, and thus wrap the list inside another object. Couldn't you just have something like the following?

```
public class List2 {

    private List list;

    public String getName() {
        return "name";
    }

    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an extra class would be redundant, try using the following:

```
<c:set var="listName"><jsp:getProperty name="list" property="name"/></c:set>
<c:out value="${listName}"/>
```