# how to print an alias attribute in JSP file using @Query annotation

Tags: spring-data-jpa

This is rows in database.

```
group userid
1    a
2    b
1    c
3    d
```

I want to query using @query annotation about

```
@Query(value ="SELECT *, count(*) as cnt FROM user group by body order by cnt DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> getGroupRanking();
```

and, i expect to result about

```
group cnt
1     2
2     1
3     d
```

but `List<User>` collection is not accept to 'cnt' attribute which was alias.
another reason not to accept, User defined class was not containing 'cnt' attribute. i was defined 'cnt' attribute in User Class like following code.

```
public class User{
 @Column(name ="group")
 private String group;
 ..

 private Integer cnt;
 public Integer getCnt(){ return cnt; }
 public void setCnt(Integer cnt){ this.cnt = cnt; }

}
```

Although I will prevent to update the schema, The above code update the schema. because

appConfig.xml configuration was set like this

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

i don't want to update schema, and i want to display cnt attribute in JSP file through User Class(bean) when i using @Query annotation. how to accept a 'cnt' attribute using the User class without update schema?
'as' keyword usage not containing in detail([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query))

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what you need, but I'll try... ))

First create a projection:

```java
public interface UserCount {
     User getUser();
     long getUserCount();
}
```

Then create a repository query method which return this projection:

```java
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select u as user, count(u) as userCount from User u group by u order by userCount desc")
    List<UserCount> getUserCounts();
}
```

Then you can get list of `UserCount` projections and send it to your JSP view.

Additional reading:

- [Projections on repository query methods](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods)
- [Data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

#### UPDATE

**Controller**:

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autoware
    private UserRepo repo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String withCount(Model model) {

        List<UserCount> userCounts = getUserCounts();
        model.addAttribute("userCounts", userCounts);

        return "userCounts";
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```jsp
<table>
  ...
  <c:forEach items="${userCounts}" var="item">
    <tr>
      <td>${item.user.group}</td>
      ...
      <td>${item.userCount}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Some info: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830047), [2](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

I recommend to switch from **jsp** to [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org).

Comment: You gave the proper answer to the intent of the question.
I have a question, how do I print out a jsp file using getUser() and getUserCount()  in the interface?

Comment: Don't understand you. How do you imagine printing a jsp file using a repository method that works with the database only? Or you want to ask how to use repo method in mvc controller to display its value in jsp page?..

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to using methodgetUser() and getUserCount() in jsp file. but I can't handle it. I can't understand projection. and why call alias( ${item.userCount} ) instead of method name( ${item.getUserCount()} ).

Comment: more than anything, my jsp file error has occured.  like this.

`Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/app] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/group.jsp at line 35

33:    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
34:     <div class="b-field-tit">
35:     ${item.count}
36:     </div>
37:    </c:forEach>
38:  `

my database ;is mariadb, this syntax is not correct

`@Query("select u as user, count(u) as userCount from User u group by u ` 

alias 'u' of the table name not accept to query syntax in mariadb

Comment: my query of the annotation like this, `@Query(value = "select name, count(*) as userCount from User group by body order by userCount desc", nativeQuery = false)` abobe the query is working in jsp file. like this. `${item}` 
but, result log is useless.  `[Ljava.lang.Object;@466a8d2a [Ljava.lang.Object;@720087c ...` this expression in jsp file is not working `${item.userCount}`

Comment: JSP is a too huge area for one question. [RTM](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=jsp+howto)

Comment: Thank you for your sincere reply. I follow your answer, i was setup thymeleaf. and later, i will try this again.